# Aquire container failed! in Eclipse IDE at Update Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I'm updating maven dependencies in my project with Maven Update command of Eclipse IDE 2022-12 version (last version) and the ide if saying to my the next error:

[image]

Do anyone know how to solve this error?

I'm deleted .metadata folder, purge local repository .m2 for maven and nothing was well.

Thanks!! And Happy New Year 2023!!

Comment: Probably something to report to https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues, with more details of your project (it's a very unique misspelling of "acquire").

Comment: Just had a similar issue today in Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0), just recently updated. Closing projects, then Eclipse and reopening them back solved the issue for now. But this is indeed very strange, especially, as pointed out by @nitind, spelling of 'acquire'. I did not find any other instances of this issue anywhere, but here. Very weird...

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1123 They recommend using a snapshot as of now. Not sure if it is been currently released.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen.  It was caused by being unable to find a parent pom of the correct version.  I.E. my workspace had a project that used a pom in another project.  The parent had been advanced to a new snapshot version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT, and the child was referring to 0.0.1, but that version wasn't out in our Nexus repo yet.  So there was no place to get it, either via Nexus or Workspace Resolution.

It was bad timing on my part...I didn't know this versioning work was going on  and I just had to wait until the "release" jar files had been built and pushed to our Nexus repo.

Answer (score 1):

For me the closing and re-opening of projects didn't work nor the Maven > Update Project... .

In my case it was a certain Maven plugin integration that made my pom look invalid to Eclipse. The root cause could be determined in the log file **{Eclipse workspace path}/.metadata/.log**.

```
Failed to load Effective POM
Could not read maven project
container creation failed
container creation failed
can't create plexus container for basedir = /home/linux/customproject because the extension build.mavenextensions:ci-friendly-versions-extension:1.0.0 can't be loaded (defined in /home/linux/customproject/.mvn/extensions.xml).
```

In there I had a "**Failed to load Effective POM**" message caused by **Maven plugin ci-friendly-versions-extension** which didn't exist at the specified location. The config file located at **{my custom project dir}/.mvn/extensions.xml** was pointing to "**ci-friendly-versions-extension:1.0.0**" which was unavailable in my Maven repository so I had to point it to "**ci-friendly-versions-extension:3.0.0**" which did exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>ci-friendly-versions-extension</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Then a maven rebuild and project refresh in Eclipse was sufficient to have the "aquire container failed" error go away.

Comment: The error I was facing was different, but the tip for the workspace log file helped me find my specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, closing all projects in different working sets except the one I want to build solved the issue for the moment (of course only a temporary solution).